# App crashes after downloaded from Play Store?

Tags: android, apk, google-play

Emulating it, all goes well.
But then, exporting the apk and installing it on different, real, phones, or after downloading the app from the playstore:

```
> 08-16 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 08-16 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ActivityHome}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.example.ActivityHome" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
> "/data/app/com.example-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-1,
> /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 08-16 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):
>   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
> 08-16 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
> 08-16 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 08-16
> 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):     at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
> 08-16 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-16
> 23:56:25.450: E/AndroidRuntime(5079):     at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-16 23:56:25.450:
```

22 more...

I don't really know how to fix...

Comment: please tell me how you see those error after downloading it from Play Store. I have similar need but don't know how to see logcat after downloading it from play store.        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24674095/app-crashes-after-downloading-from-play-store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-downloaded android support library, re-ordered dependecies, cleaned the project and rebuilt the workspace: ~100KB was added to the final package in this way. In this way, everything re-started to work.

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages point to, it's not finding the class.

Did you change the package name when you released your App? When changing the package name you have to update your `AndroidManifest.xml` file too, to reflect the changes.

i.e. if your Activity has a full name of `lu.gian.uniwhere.beta.ActivityHome` and you change it to `lu.gian.uniwhere.ActivityHome` on release, you will also have to update your Manifest

from

```
<activity class=".beta.ActivityHome">...</Activity>
```

to

```
<activity class=".ActivityHome">...</Activity>
```

This can also happen, when moving a file (within your IDE/Eclipse) from one folder to another, which will also change the package name, as folders in Eclipse/IDE act as package structure.

Comment: I switched the project back, prior to folder renaming: unfortunately, it still does it... Please, take a look to the edited question. LogCat updated.