# App crashes after downloading from Play Store?

Tags: android, proguard, google-play

My app works fine in all devices before uploading it to play store. Now i have upload new version.

```
android:versionCode="7"
android:versionName="6.2"
```

Please tell me how can i see logcat after downloading my app from Play Store. Is it possible to detect or get error . How can i resolve this issue.

One problem i found while building apk was.

I have enabled proguard. now i delete that file `proguard-project.txt` . then eclipse let me create an apk . Now tell me how to resolve this issue.

My half problem will be solved if someone tell me how to see logcat of an app after downloading it from eclipse.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: install a logcat app from the Play Store.dat may solve your problm

Comment: I have solve my issue by simply cleaning the Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When app crashes you can see two buttons, force stop / OK and report.
Click on report button and there you will find various tabs. In one of the tabs you will get stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Buddy , I find that my splash activity is not found Now how can i resolve it.

Comment: check it in android mainfest.xml

Answer (score 2):

To see logs just use 'adb' tool. Connect device, type in a console:

```
adb logcat
```

And launch your app.

And I would recommend you to use some service which logs app crashes and exceptions. For instance https://crashlytics.com

Comment: @+10 Thanks for the guide..   I find that my splash activity is not found Now how can i resolve it

Answer (score -1):

DO as below on build.gradle:

```
buildfeature{
         release {
              minifyEnable false
                 ----
              }
          }
```